# hiding an asp.net generated <span> breaks my javascript form validation

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation, hidden

so I am using javascript to validate an address field simply to pull the zip code off the end.

I have two asp:Labels that I show and hide to inform the user. It works great, the labels show when needed and the validation works how I want it, the problem comse when I try to hide them. One of the labels shows and hides just fine, but whenever I try to hide the other the script breaks

```
<script>
        function isvalid() 
        {
            var zip = MainContent_tbx_Appt_Address.value.slice(-5);
            if (zip == "") {
                MainContent_lbl_Add_validate2.hidden = true;
                MainContent_lbl_Add_Validate.hidden = false;

            }
            else if (!zip.match('[0-9]{5}')) {
                //MainContent_lbl_Add_validate.hidden = true;
                MainContent_lbl_Add_validate2.hidden = false;

            }
            else
            {
                //MainContent_lbl_Add_validate.hidden = true;
                MainContent_lbl_Add_validate2.hidden = true;

            }

        }
    </script>

            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Add_Validate" style="z-index:100;" Name="lbl_Add_Validate" DataPoint="dp_Add_Validate" runat="server" hidden="true" Text="Address is required"></asp:Label> 

            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Add_validate2" style="z-index:100;" Name="lbl_Add_Validate2" DataPoint="dp_Add_Validate2" runat="server" hidden="true" Text="Invalid address format"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbx_Appt_Address" onblur="isvalid()" style="z-index:100;" Name="tbx_Appt_Address" DataPoint="dp_Appt_Address" runat="server" Rows="4" TextMode="MultiLine"  Height="65px"  Width="200px" value="Address" onFocus="if (this.value == this.defaultValue) { this.value = ''; }" placeholder="Address">Address</asp:TextBox>
```

this is my code in my asp file and when it hits the client side it spits out this

```
<span id="MainContent_lbl_Add_Validate" name="lbl_Add_Validate" datapoint="dp_Add_Validate" hidden="true" style="z-index:100;">Address is required</span>
<span id="MainContent_lbl_Add_validate2" name="lbl_Add_Validate2" datapoint="dp_Add_Validate2" hidden="true" style="z-index:100;">Invalid address format</span>
<br/>
<textarea name="ctl00$MainContent$tbx_Appt_Address" rows="4" cols="20" id="MainContent_tbx_Appt_Address" datapoint="dp_Appt_Address" value="Address" onfocus="if (this.value == this.defaultValue) { this.value = ''; }" placeholder="Address" onblur="return isvalid()" style="height:65px;width:200px;z-index:100;">Address</textarea>
```

everything else works as long as I have MainContent_lbl_Add_validate.hidden = true; commented out, but if I have ether of them run it breaks

Comment: The lower-case `hidden` property/field suggest that this is not part of the original asp.net api. Could you show us the declaration of `MainContent_lbl_Add_validate` and `MainContent_lbl_Add_validate2`? Are you manually setting ctrl.Attributes["hidden"]="true"? Have you done any debugging and can tell us any error messages / stack traces other than "it breaks"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In aspx pages if you are not using jQuery, try to get elements using  document.getElementById('MainContent_tbx_Appt_Address'), and if you are using microsoft ajax frameworks you can use $get('MainContent_lbl_Add_validate'), these are the right ways to refer elements on DOM.

Editing: ok, looking your code with more accuracy I saw that you made a mistake on span ids, specifically at 'V' char. Check the case on ids and your script will run.

Comment: I put document.getElementById for tbx_ and no change so I put it on all of the object calls and it broke

Comment: Yup that did it, nice catch

Answer (score 0):

If you hide an element that has "runat=server", you might think that ASP will render the control styled so that it is invisible-- meaning you can later unhide it using Javascript.  That's not how it work.  If you set hidden=true, the element isn't rendered at all.  Your Javascript is gagging on the reference to the missing element and halting execution, so your valiator code doesn't ever get a chance to run.

To render a hidden element, mark it up like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_Add_Validate" style="z-index:100;" Name="lbl_Add_Validate" DataPoint="dp_Add_Validate" runat="server" style="visibility: hidden" Text="Address is required"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: but I can show and hide MainContent_lbl_Add_validate2 all I want and the validator code does work just not when I try to re-hide MainContent_lbl_Add_validate

Comment: This post describes what happens when you set "Visible=false", while "hidden=true" seems to be something the OP forwards as html5 attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would let JQuery handle this, which you can do in .aspx:

```
$(function () {
  $('#tbx_Appt_Address').blur(function(){
    var text_input = $('tbx_Appt_Address').val();

    //additional logic with conditions

    if (text_input=='') 
    {
        $('lbl_Add_Validate').show();
    }

    //etc etc
  });
```

});

Comment: This is almost how the built-in asp.net validators work, there's not reason to build it manually. It'll also easily break if control structure changes (and the automatically generated ids changes).